# Using too much of Hotspot hurts the iPad?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, tethering

I have a iPad mini2 *(cellular)*. Recently my modem has been broken and to use the internet via my laptop I use a personal hotspot connection. I mean I connect to my ipad by my laptop for using the internet.

As I've mentioned in the title of my question, I do that too much. For example 10 hours per day. Now I want to know, should I stop doing that? would it hurts my ipad?

You know, I feel the connection has slowed recently, I mean when I turn personal hotspot on in my ipad, it takes 1 min to my laptop find it and connect to it. I think that happened faster already.

Comment: Does your cellular provider throttle your data speeds after you've used a certain amount of data?  Even "unlimited" plans can do this, there is no general answer to this question it's very specific to your carrier and plan.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I stop doing that?

The only reason you may want to stop is to avoid going over your cellular data limit (if any).

> Will it hurt my iPad?

No, this wont "hurt" your iPad, however it's a process that requires the iPad to work a bit harder than normal, meaning you can expect these while you are using the hotspot:

- Shorter battery life for the iPad
- Slower Performance on the iPad
- Slower internet speeds than usual for all devices